# How To Dynamically Add Arbitrary Number Of Line Series To WPF Toolkit Chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, charts

Is it possible to draw multiple lines in a single toolkit chart where line numbers are determined at run-time? I prefer a MVVM way of binding lines to a collection. For example below, there is only one "LineSeries" to be shown, but what if I want to show multiple lines. Thank you!

```
            <ch:Chart.Series>
            <ch:LineSeries Title="{Binding Title}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding  DataPoints}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=X}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Y}">
            </ch:LineSeries>
        </ch:Chart.Series>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 3** - Adding a Test button:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="498" Height="277">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="ADD" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="226,292,217.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Window:

```
    int index;
    MyViewModel2 viewModel;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel = new MyViewModel2();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            pc.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i * (2 + index) });

        LineSeries series1 = new LineSeries();
        series1.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        series1.IndependentValuePath = "X";
        series1.ItemsSource = pc;
        chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        viewModel.MyList.Add(pc);

        index++;
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT 2** - Adding `Series` dynamically:

XAML:

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart1" Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel2
{
    public List<PointCollection> MyList { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel2()
    {
        MyList = new List<PointCollection>();
    }
}
```

Window:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel = new MyViewModel2();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        PointCollection pc1 = new PointCollection();
        PointCollection pc2 = new PointCollection();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            pc1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i * 2 });
            pc2.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i * 3 });
        }

        LineSeries series1 = new LineSeries();
        series1.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        series1.IndependentValuePath = "X";
        series1.ItemsSource = pc1;
        chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        viewModel.MyList.Add(pc1);

        LineSeries series2 = new LineSeries();
        series2.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        series2.IndependentValuePath = "X";
        series2.ItemsSource = pc2;
        chart1.Series.Add(series2);

        viewModel.MyList.Add(pc2);
    }
```

**EDIT 1** - This should get you going:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPointCollection1}"/>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPointCollection2}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PointCollection MyPointCollection1 { get; set; }
    public PointCollection MyPointCollection2 { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyPointCollection1 = new PointCollection();
        MyPointCollection2 = new PointCollection();
    }
}
```

Window:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            viewModel.MyPointCollection1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i * 2 });
            viewModel.MyPointCollection2.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i * 3 });
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my problem is that I don't know how many lineSeries will be, so I cannot define a fixed number of MyPointCollection# and LineSeries

Comment: Please see **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Please see **EDIT 3** - Added a test button.

Comment: @user2391685 do you have any follow up questions on this?